# Go error: non-constant array bound

Tags: go

I'm trying to calculate the necessary length for an array in a merge sort implementation I'm writing in `go`. It looks like this:

```
func merge(array []int, start, middle, end int) {
  leftLength := middle - start + 1
  rightLength := end - middle
  var left [leftLength]int
  var right [rightLength]int
  //...
}
```

I then get this complaint when running `go test`:

```
./mergesort.go:6: non-constant array bound leftLength
./mergesort.go:7: non-constant array bound rightLength
```

I assume `go` does not enjoy users instantiating an Array's length with a calculated value. It only accepts *constants*. Should I just give up and use a slice instead? I expect a *slice* is a dynamic array meaning it's either a linked list or copies into a larger array when it gets full.

Comment: What do you mean you "expect" a slice is a dynamic array? [Read what a slice actually is](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals).

Comment: Thats what Slices are made for in Go. Under the hood they are just pointers to arrays.

Comment: @TimCooper interesting. Instead of giving Array's a complex interface themselves slices are another layer that makes array manipulation simpler?

Comment: @TimCooper see the 3rd definition https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expect

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You can't instantiate an array like that with a value calculated at runtime. Instead use make to initialize a slice with the desired length. It would look like this;

```
left := make([]int, leftLength)
```